# Dislpay custom attribute in Product view page - in Product description template

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, rwd-theme, page-layouts

I am working on magento 1.9.2 RWD theme and I am trying to display the product additional info via custom attribute.

I have created the attribute -
    Admin   Default Store View
    faq       FAQ

I added a new block FAQ in the layout.xml and it is displaying on the product page.When I am adding an cms block it is displaying properly.

But When I am trying to get the value of faq attribute through admin panel it is giving error and not displying. My code of faq.phtml  in the product/view/faq.phtml are as follow-

```
/**

 * Product description template

 *

 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Description

 */

?>

<?php 

 $_product = $this->getProduct();

//$pid= $_product->getId();

//$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);

/*  $ids = $_product->getCategoryIds();

 $categoryId = (isset($ids[0]) ? $ids[0] : null); */

?>
 <?php

 if($_product->getFAQ()){ ?>

    <?php echo $_product->getFAQ();?>

 <?php } ?>
```

I am getting the below Error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getFAQ() on null in /home/berkowitsclinic/public_html/hairwits.com/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/faq.phtml on line 107

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Which type of attribute you are created? is it dropdown or multiselect ? if Yes then above code should work but if you have text type attribute then try to call by below code....

```
<?php

         if($_product->getFAQ()){ ?>

            <?php echo $product->getAttributeText('faq'); ;?>

         <?php } ?>
```

and if this is not worked then try to with below code....

```
<?php

     if($_product->getFAQ()){ ?>

        <?php echo $product->getData('faq');?>

     <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I used this code but unfortunately error is not coming but nothing is displaying.  Attribute type is test area.

Comment: I also tried  to change the code as it is Text Area  but no response-<?php

 if($_product->getFAQ()){ ?>

    <?php echo $product->getAttributeTextArea('faq'); ?>

 <?php } ?>

Comment: check updated answer,sure it will work and also check settings in admin.

Comment: @ Akgola in your updated answer - echo echo is 2 times.. when using  the same it is giving syntax error -  unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) and when using single echo nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Login you admin Catalog->attribute->Mange attribute select faq

change **Used in Product Listing** should be **Yes**

Comment: Used in product Listing option is YES , still not showing anything.

Comment: Are you get product data $_product->getData() ?.       what your product attribute code?

Comment: Check you attribute set name

Comment: Attribute set name is Default - and attribute code is faq   & importantly faq attribute is visible in admin panel Catalogue > manage Product > Faq

Comment: Assign some values in and  try $_product->getFaq();

Comment: Tried with pre assigned value still not appearing. I cross checked with my data tables. all the rows are getting values.  Any idea how to print the data table values on product page under div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs"